Is there a way to call a Grape API directly through the Ruby on Rails console with appropriate params passed as part of the call
I would like to directly call a Grape API as part of a Rails application through the rails console. How do we directly call a Grape API from the rails console with appropriate params passed as part of the call?
I'm currently on Rails 7 and I'm using Grape 2.0.0

Why bother with the http request and its associated overhead/complication? Execute that handler body directly.

But if you do want to go through http, then it's not any different from any 3rd party api endpoint. So use Faraday or RestClient or whatever you normally use to make api requests to external services.
